# Use a pcollection as input of another pcollection

Tags: mapreduce, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Using python sdk in google dataflow, I would like to do a query like this:

> query_a_and_b = "SELECT a, b FROM TableA"

This query returns a list of tuples i'd like to use to perform more queries:

> query_param = SELECT * from TableA WHERE a = {} and b = {}.format(a, b)
>   (here i set TableA but it will also be used with TableB, C and D that are inner joined with TableA...)

So what I am trying to do:

```py
coll = (p
    | 'read a_b_tuples' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=query_a_and_b, use_standard_sql=True)) 
    | 'Build SQL' >> beam.Map(lambda x: query_param.format(x['a'], x['b'])) 
    | 'Query pardo' >> beam.ParDo(lambda q: [beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=q, use_standard_sql=True))])
    | 'Save' >> beam.io.WriteToText('results.csv')
)
```

I am not sure that the best approach and it does not work. What is the preferred way to achieve this in dataflow?

Ultimately, each of these queries will return a small amount of rows (less than 5k), that i'd like to load in a pandas dataframe for filtering/processing, then combine all TableA,B,C,D for every tuple (a,b) and write each tuple datafarm to a csv file the result.

I might be map-reducing the problem incorrectly in a sense I could use the beam functions to group by a and b and then do my processing...?

Comment: Couldn't you just write your SQL query to BigQuery using Common Table Expressions and do all the joins in SQL + use UNION ALL to combine the result so that you will keep the Apache Beam complexity to minimum (+ you will have single source)

Comment: The queries would be a bit complex due to a lot of computations. we have  5 different tables with different structures. it appears easier to treat them independently and merge the aggregated results. i already have some code to run on one (a,b) tuple manually so i would like to just iterate through all other tuples and leveraging dataflow to automatically scale.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beam doesn't directly support this for BigQuery yet. Some other transforms support similar use cases, e.g. `JdbcIO.readAll()` can query a database for a collection of query parameters, `TextIO.readAll()` can read a collection of filenames - but `BigQueryIO` doesn't do this yet, neither in the Java nor Python SDKs.

In your "Query pardo", you can instead explicitly talk to the [BigQuery REST API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query) - it should be fine because your queries return a small number of results.

Comment: well that means I need to implement the exponential back off and some other things that came for free in the sdk.... not what I need :(